# How to display blob image in react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, blob

Here is my code:

```
<Image source={BlobImage} style={{ height: 200, width: null, flex: 1 }} />
```

Where BlobImage is an image in blob string like this`c916851b-3e53-432d-8d18-3de293776859?offset=0&size=371537`.

Edit:

I upload a base64 image to cpanel, and it is automatically cast to Blob. When I fetch the data from cpanel, I get a buffer array and unable to display it. I tried this but it doesn't work

```
var blob = new Blob([img], {type: "image/png"})
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

And in render

```
<Image source={{uri:blobUrl}} style={{ height: 200, width: null, flex: 1 }} />
```

Where `img` is the raw data from cpanel and it's a byte array.

This is how I get the data using react-native-photo-upload

```
<PhotoUpload
    onPhotoSelect={avatar => {
                   if (avatar) {
                       this.setState({
                           imageUrl: avatar
                       });
                   }}}>
```

Answer (score 24):

You can convert the `blob` to `base64` from [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) api and then display it.

**Code:**

```
const fileReaderInstance = new FileReader();
 fileReaderInstance.readAsDataURL(blob); 
 fileReaderInstance.onload = () => {
     base64data = fileReaderInstance.result;                
     console.log(base64data);
 }
```

and display it once you get it as:

```
<Image source={{uri: base64ImageData}} style={{ height: 200, width: null, flex: 1 }} />
```

Comment: Is this still the best option when using expo?

Comment: Works as of Nov, 2021.

Comment: Can you send the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this

```
<Image source={{uri: BlobImage}} style={{ height: 200, width: null, flex: 1 }}/>
```