# React native (Android) - Create URL.createObjectURL(blob)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Im trying to create a blob url to use string as file for JwPlayer subtitles.

subtitles are loaded like this:

```
const playlistItem = {
    ...
    tracks: [
        {
            file: 'https://myfakesite.org/subtitles.vtt',
            label: 'en'
        }
    ]
}
```

So because jwplayer dont accept my source (subtitles.ass) i converted .ass to .vtt resulting as string.

Like this:

```
var vttRaw = `WEBVTT

00:00:25.520 --> 00:00:29.250
Naquele dia,
a humanidade foi lembrada...

00:00:35.110 --> 00:00:38.180
do terror de estar à mercê deles`;
```

As jwplayer needs a url, i converted this string to blob url:

```
//Generate blob
var blob = new Blob([vttRaw], {
    type: "text/vtt; charset=utf-8"
});

//Generate url
var vtt_url = URL.createObjectURL(blob) + "#.vtt";
```

In web browser that works, but in react-native-android results in a error.

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Cannot create URL for blob!
```

[blob error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD7WV.png)

I think the problem is to generate a blob url, anyone know what can i do?

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue in React Native for Android. The following worked in iOS but not Android

```
URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

Try passing base64 data rather than the url, like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49915625/8656845).

Maybe something like this:

```
//Generate blob
var blob = new Blob([vttRaw], {
    type: "text/vtt; charset=utf-8"
});

const fileReaderInstance = new FileReader();
fileReaderInstance.readAsDataURL(blob);
fileReaderInstance.onload = () => {
    base64 = fileReaderInstance.result;
    vtt_data = base64;
}
```